# All time Active service even on uninstalling

Tags: android, service

I am developing an app where i need to keep background service running even if user uninstalls app. this is more like what uber did with its ios app to track users (https://www.wired.com/2017/04/uber-didnt-track-users-deleted-app-still-broke-rules/).

I tried to make service as system service which actual a bad idea.

`ServiceManager.addService("downloader", new MyService());`

looking forward for help.

Comment: That's not what that article says they did - that's talking about detecting reinstalls on the same physical device.

Comment: I looks to me like you are trying to create some sort of malware / spyware...

Comment: On uninstalling what on what basis you can expect this ? It removes all the app components

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing an app where i need to keep background service running even if user uninstalls app.

That is not possible, fortunately.